# How do I Change Shape Color on Click in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, shapes, fill

I wish to change the color of a shape In excel upon clicking on It.
But I am new to VBA and not sure how to write the code for this.
Any method will be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, you should try something by your own and show us what you tried, even if the code does not work. Secondly, you should should take care of presenting [Minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do you have in mind a particular shape type?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy this code in a standard module:

```
Sub MyShape_Click()
  Dim sh As Shape
   Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
   If sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
   Else
        sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  End If
End Sub
```

2. Right click on the shape in discussion and choose `Assign Macro...`. In the window which opens you should search and select the above Sub macro name (MyShape_Click). Press OK and test the solution. It firstly will color the shape in red and then alternatively in blue and red.